# reload tableview from navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iPhone development.

I have a navigation controller which loads a tableview. The class identity of the tableview is a tableViewController class.

I want to know how to refresh the table view from the navigation controller.

I know within the tableViewController i can use the

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Sorry if i am vague. 
Thanks in advance.

**after feedback:**

Here is the navigation controller

```
@interface slNavController : UINavigationController{

UIToolbar *toolbar;
slTableViewController *tableVC;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) slTableViewController *tableVC;
```

where slTableViewController is the Delegate of the tableView that needs to be refreshed.

and where i needed to refresh the table i used

```
[tableVC.tableView reloadData];
```

Here is slTableViewController header

```
@interface slTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

IBOutlet UITableView *slTableView;
NSMutableArray *list;
TryAppDelegate *appDelegate;
//UIToolbar *toolbar;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

}
```

But still not able to refresh the tableview.

Comment: What do you mean "from the navigation controller?" Did you subclass UINavigationController?

Comment: i mean in the navigationcontroller implementation file

Comment: So you are subclassing navigationController?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by subclassing ?

Comment: What navigationController implementation file are you talking about? Is it a class that you have written? You have a class that you wrote that is a tableViewController class... this class is a subclass of UITableViewController, because it inherits from it. You'll need at least a basic understanding of this to deal with iPhone development. Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Yes..I have subclassed navigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some viewController which is the delegate of the tableView. Send reloadData to that controller, e.g.

```
[viewController.tableView reloadData];
```

If you know where in the stack the viewController is, you can access it through the navController. For instance, if it happens to be the rootViewController, then you can do

HomesViewController *homesController = [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

If it is Navigation based application you want to reload the data of table view, You have to write in view will appear like this

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your navigationController a pointer to the tableViewController.

In the .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) YourTableViewController *tableViewController;
```

Then when you want to reload data:

```
[tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Check that the pointer you are calling reloadData on actually points to your table... could the pointer be not getting set, and still nil?